# Fourier transform of $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^4}$ and $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}=xf(x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

Let $f(x)=x/(1+x^4)$, the improper integral of which exists.

I computed the Fourier transform of $f$, to be:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}(f(x))=\hat{f}(k)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(H(-k)ie^{(k/\sqrt{2})}sin(k/\sqrt{2})+H(k)e^{-(ik/\sqrt{2})}sinh(k/\sqrt{2}) \right), k \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{equation}
H(k)=\begin{cases} 0, & k<0 \\ 1, & k\geq 0\end{cases}
\end{equation}

- My first question is whether this is correct or not.
- My second and last one, has to do with the computation of the Fourier transform for $g(x)=x^2/(1+x^4)$. I am pretty sure that I do not have to go through the whole procedure again in order to compute this one. Actually, I think that I could just as well compute the transform for $h(x)=1/(1+x^4)$ and then derive the rest from this one.

But, how?

Thank you!

Comment: Under suitable conditions, $({\cal F} f)' = i{\cal F}(x \mapsto x f(x))$.

Comment: @copper.hat I am aware of this property, but how can I apply it here? :/

Comment: $g(x) = xf(x)$, so ${\cal F} g = -i ({\cal F} f)'$.

Comment: You should specify which fourier transform you are using. Because derivative identity depends on the fourier parameters

Comment: I am using $\mathcal{F}(f)=\hat{f}(k)=1/(\sqrt{2\pi})\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$, but I think that I have resolved the question, since I can use this property! Thank you @copper.hat. But, as far as my first question is concerned, is that a correct result?

Comment: You used the residues as (-1)^{1/4} on the upper half plane? Then it should be correct unless you made a calculation error. However that $H(k)$ function seems unnecessary to me. A more elegant method would be, when changing the variable (for example) $xk=z$, you multiply the integral with $\text{sign}(k)$ and this takes care of everything that might be caused by the sign of k.

Comment: I took the residues once for the upper half plane and then for the rest below. After that I just did the calculations.  But I am interested in what exactly do you mean by the $sign(k)$ multiplication? I mean, how would the final outcome look in the way you describe?

Comment: I mean, how would the final outcome look in the way you describe?|| I'm sorry, I don't want to do it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I thought it was not a long procedure since you had the final outcome already! I did not want to put you through this, I know it is painful :P Well, thank you again!